# How can I add items to the Admin Toolbar?

Tags: 8, navigation

In Drupal 8, I want to add a menu item to the Admin Toolbar with a submenu, with different links.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add items to the admin toolbar in two ways:

**As content:**

In ui `/admin/structure/menu/manage/admin`

or in code:

```
$item = \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::create([
  'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/<front>'],
  'title' => 'Front Page',
  'menu_name' => 'admin',
]);
$item->save();
```

**Or in static configuration files:**

```
system.admin:
  title: Administration
  route_name: system.admin
  weight: 9
  menu_name: admin
system.admin_content:
  title: Content
  description: 'Find and manage content.'
  route_name: system.admin_content
  parent: system.admin
  weight: -10
system.admin_structure:
  route_name: system.admin_structure
  parent: system.admin
  description: 'Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc.'
  title: Structure
  weight: -8
system.themes_page:
  route_name: system.themes_page
  title: Appearance
  description: 'Select and configure themes.'
  parent: system.admin
  weight: -6
```

This is the start of **system.links.menu.yml**, which defines the admin menu as we know it from D8. You can add your own entries in **mymodule.links.menu.yml**.

Edit:

To add an item to the top row, use the hook `mymodule_toolbar()`. This is an example from the tour module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_toolbar().
 */
function tour_toolbar() {
  $items = [];
  $items['tour'] = [
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => [
        'user.permissions',
      ],
    ],
  ];

  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access tour')) {
    return $items;
  }

  $items['tour'] += array(
    '#type' => 'toolbar_item',
    'tab' => array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Tour'),
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('toolbar-icon', 'toolbar-icon-help'),
        'aria-pressed' => 'false',
      ),
    ),
    '#wrapper_attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('tour-toolbar-tab', 'hidden'),
      'id' => 'toolbar-tab-tour',
    ),
    '#attached' => array(
      'library' => array(
        'tour/tour',
      ),
    ),
  );
 return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @4k4 but when I try to add it through the UI the item doesn't appear in the first level of the Administer option of the toolbar.

Comment: To get an item in the top row, you have to use a hook. I put an example in the answer.

Comment: thank you for your answers, in the end I'm going to use the module [Toolbar Menu] (https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_menu) that adapts to what I need.

Comment: Also worth to have a look at the devel module and their implementation of `hook_toolbar` and a `ToolbarHandler`.

Comment: @4k4: Where do you add the first code?

Comment: I added an entry in `mymodule.links.menu.yml` and it did not work...

Comment: nvm it works, forgot the `.menu` part, my module happen to have the word "menu" as part of it's name, so threw me off.

Comment: I think it would be useful to clarify what means " use the hook mymodule_toolbar(). ". I think once somebody knows how to "use a hook", he won't have problems with adding menus. But this hook business is obscure for newcomers (and even for content managers using Drupal for 10 or 20 years, if they only used the UI so far). Where to put that code? etc.

Answer (score 4):

For all who wonder where they may put code from previous answer – You can use it in MYMODULE.install for example

```
function MYMODULE_install(){
    $item = \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::create([
      'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/admin/link'],
      'title' => 'Link title',
      'menu_name' => 'admin',
    ]);
    $item->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 9 a top menu item and submenu items can be added in the my_module.links.menu.yml

See here the example from `group.links.menu.yml`

```
system.admin_group:
  title: 'Groups'
  description: 'Find and manage groups, group types and group settings.'
  route_name: 'entity.group.collection'
  parent: 'system.admin'
  weight: 3
```

And then to add submenu items, use the menu link you defined above as parent

```
another.menu_link:
  title: 'Example submenu'
  description: 'Example description'
  route_name: my_route.name
  parent: 'system.admin_group'
  weight: 0
```