# Add Language Switcher on admin toolbar

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n, navigation, transliteration

What is the correct way for adding Language Switcher (Dropdown) or links on the admin toolbar menu from my custom module or from a contributed module?

[image]

Comment: There is tree ways to add items to the admin toolbar, take a look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215394/how-can-i-add-items-to-the-admin-toolbar),

Comment: I've tried all of these ways, but I don't know how to add a language switcher on the top of admin menu

Comment: 4k4’s answer is how to do it. You’ll need to work out how to render the language switcher but that’s a simple google search away

Comment: I know how I can render the language switcher or list of language but the issue with me that I've tried the code and the menu link was added but not added on the top beside (Manage, Shortcut, ..), I can only see it on the /admin/structure/menu/manage/admin

Comment: That's a list of tabs, it's not designed to have arbitrary elements in it. Not that it couldn't, theoretically...have a look at core/themes/stable/templates/navigation/toolbar.html.twig, that should make it clearer which variable you need to get the render array for the language switcher into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got something up and running via [`hook_toolbar`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21toolbar%21toolbar.api.php/function/hook_toolbar/8.2.x). Only thing left is, that you can't click directly on the "Language: EN" string in the toolbar. You have to click slightly next to it. Maybe you can fix this.

[image]

Apart from that, please also have a look at the Devel module and their implementation of `hook_toolbar` where they have an extra `src/ToolbarHandler.php` class for everything. You better should rebuild the code below into a dedicated handler.

---

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Link;

/**
 * Implements hook_toolbar().
 */
function MYMODULE_toolbar() {

  // Get languages, get current route.
  $current_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();
  $route = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')
    ->isFrontPage() ? '<front>' : '<current>';

  // Get links.
  $links = [];
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
    $url = new Url($route, [], ['language' => $language]);
    $links[] = [
      '#markup' => Link::fromTextAndUrl($language->getName(), $url)
        ->toString(),
    ];
  }

  // Set cache.
  $items['admin_toolbar_langswitch'] = [
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => [
        'languages:language_interface',
        'url',
      ],
    ],
  ];

  // Build toolbar item and tray.
  $items['admin_toolbar_langswitch'] += [
    '#type'   => 'toolbar_item',
    '#weight' => 999,
    'tab'     => [
      '#type'       => 'html_tag',
      '#tag'        => 'div',
      '#value'      => '<span>' . t('Language') . '</span>: <span class="current-language">' . strtoupper($current_language) . '</span>',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['toolbar-item-admin-toolbar-langswitch'],
        'title' => t('Admin Toolbar Langswitch'),
      ],
    ],
    'tray'    => [
      '#heading' => t('Admin Toolbar Langswitch'),
      'content'  => [
        '#theme'      => 'item_list',
        '#items'      => $links,
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['toolbar-menu'],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by `'contexts' => [
        'languages:language_interface',
        'url',
      ],`

Comment: @MohamedOsamaGbril – These are cache contexts. They should be sensitive enough to ensure the language string in the toolbar gets updated when switching through languages. But when the title of your toolbar item will just be "Language" you can probably remove that.

Answer (score 1):

The example above for hook_toolbar is almost perfect.  I fixed it, see code below.
You just have to remove the span on the Language : EN then the click functionality works perfectly.

see my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_toolbar().
 */
function examplemodule_toolbar() {

  // Get languages, get current route.
  $current_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();
  $route = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')
    ->isFrontPage() ? '<front>' : '<current>';

  // Get links.
  $links = [];
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
    $url = new Url($route, [], ['language' => $language]);
    $links[] = [
      '#markup' => Link::fromTextAndUrl($language->getName(), $url)
        ->toString(),
    ];
  }

  // Set cache.
  $items['admin_toolbar_langswitch'] = [
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => [
        'languages:language_interface',
        'url',
      ],
    ],
  ];

  // Build toolbar item and tray.
  $items['admin_toolbar_langswitch'] += [
    '#type'   => 'toolbar_item',
    '#weight' => 999,
    'tab'     => [
      '#type'       => 'html_tag',
      '#tag'        => 'div',
      '#value'      => t('Language') . ': ' . strtoupper($current_language),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['toolbar-item-admin-toolbar-langswitch'],
        'title' => t('Admin Toolbar Langswitch'),
      ],
    ],
    'tray'    => [
      '#heading' => t('Admin Toolbar Langswitch'),
      'content'  => [
        '#theme'      => 'item_list',
        '#items'      => $links,
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['toolbar-menu'],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nowadays there is https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_language_switcher for solving this problem

Answer (score -2):

The link in the reply berramou posted doesn't mention the contrib module [toolbar_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_menu), which makes adding stuff in the toolbar more convenient than what is mentioned in the link.